# $x+\mathbb{Z}$ has finite order iff $x\in \mathbb{Q}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, quotient-group

> Show that $x+\mathbb{Z}$ of $\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$ has finite order iff $x\in \mathbb{Q}$.

I don't really see how this follows. Say, $|x+\mathbb{Z}| = n$, first of all, how can it have finite order - $\mathbb{Z}$ is infinite. I feel like I'm not understanding some very important concept in quotient groups.

Comment: It's talking about the group-theoretic order: $\mathrm{ord}(x) = \mathrm{inf} \{ n>0 | x^n = e \}$ - or in additive notation like you'd use with this one, $\mathrm{ord}(x) = \mathrm{inf} \{ n>0 | nx = 0 \}$.

Answer (score 4):

An element of an infinite group *can* have finite order; if the group is written additively, this happens if and only if $ng=0$ for some $n>0$.

In your case, if the order of $x+\mathbb{Z}$ is $n$, then
$$
n(x+\mathbb{Z})=nx+\mathbb{Z}=0+\mathbb{Z}
$$
which means $nx\in\mathbb{Z}$, hence $x\in\mathbb{Q}$.

Conversely, suppose $x=\frac{m}{n}\in\mathbb{Q}$. Can you go on and prove the element $x+\mathbb{Z}$ has finite order?

Comment: $n(\frac{m}{n}+\mathbb{Z}) = m + \mathbb{Z} = \mathbb{Z}$. (m is also in $\mathbb{Z}$) Therefore, $|\frac{m}{n}+\mathbb{Z}| = n$. Right?

Comment: @JMK Almost. The order of $\frac{m}{n}+\mathbb{Z}$ is a divisor of $n$.